# How do I update an entity with ajax from a jQuery click event in Drupal 7?

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have a custom module for notifications as a block and I am trying to use AJAX on a jQuery click event to update a timestamp in a user flag for the current user.  The module works without the AJAX. But my JavaScript and AJAX is simple at best. The working js file (no AJAX) is:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.user_notifications = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.notify-icon').click(function(e) {
      $('.notify-list').toggle();
      var $this = $(this);
      $('.notify-count').remove();
      if ($('.notify-count').length || $('.notify-list').is(':visible')) {
        $this.children().first().attr("src","path/to/flag-light.png");
      } else {
        $this.children().first().attr("src", "path/to/flag-dark.png");
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

I have added the following route for the AJAX using hook_menu():

```
function user_notifications_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user_notifications/notify'] = array( 
    'title' => 'Ajax notify button callback',
    'page callback' => 'update_user_flag',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The callback function is:

```
function update_user_flag() {
  global $user;
  $current_timestamp = time();

  // Get user_notification_flag.
  $flag = flag_get_flag('user_notifications_notify');

  // Check if flag exists, if not create the flag for the current user.
  if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($user->uid)) {
    $user_flag = flag_get_user_flags('user', $user->uid, null, null, false);
  } else {
     $flag->flag('flag', $user->uid);
    $user_flag = flag_get_user_flags('user', $user->uid, null, null, false);
  }

  // Get the flagging ID from the flagging table.
  foreach($user_flag as $flagging_object) {
    $flagging_id = $flagging_object->flagging_id;
  }

  // Load the flagging entity & update the timestamp to the current timestamp value.
  $flagging = entity_load_single('flagging', $flagging_id);
  $flagging->timestamp['und'][0]['value'] = $current_timestamp;
  entity_save('flagging', $flagging);
}
```

The ajax version (draft) of the js file is:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.user_notifications = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.notify-icon').click(function(e) {
      $('.notify-list').toggle();
      var $this = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url:'user_notifications/notify'
        data: this,
        success: function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("something went wrong");
        }
      });
      $('.notify-count').remove();
      if ($('.notify-count').length || $('.notify-list').is(':visible')) {
           $this.children().first().attr("src","path/to/flag-light.png");
      } else {
        $this.children().first().attr("src","path/to/flag-dark.png");
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

I can remove the count button defined by css with the class selector of .notify-count using jQuery (see js function).  However I need to send an asynchronous request to change the timestamp of the user flag entity so that when the page is reloaded the following conditional statement in the hook_block_view() will revert to the second test:

```
user_notifications_block_view(){

// .... standard delta info ...
// Get query info ...

// Get new notifications count.
$notify_count = _get_new_notification_count();

// Test for comments
 if (!empty($items) && ($notify_count > 0)) {
   // Insert flag icon light -indicating new comments
   $block['content']['notify_icon'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => '<li class="notify-icon"><img src="..path/to/flag-light.png" alt="New notifications" ></li>',
   );
   // Add number of new comments badge
   $block['content']['notification_count'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => '<li class="notify-count">' . $notify_count . '</li>',
   );

   // Theme content title
   $block['content']['title'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => '<ul class="notify-list"><li class="block-title"><h3>Notifications</h3></li>',
   );

   // Theme notification items in list for pre-render
   $block['content']['list'] =  array(
     '#theme' => 'item_list__user_notifications',
     '#items' => $items,
     '#pre_render' => array(
       'user_notifications_item_list_child_render'
           ),
   );
 } else {
   // Insert flag icon dark - indicating no new comments
   $block['content']['notify_icon'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => '<li class="notify-icon"><img src="../path/to/flag-dark.png" class="img-swap" alt="No new notifications" ></li>',
   );

   // Theme content title
   $block['content']['title'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => '<ul class="notify-list"><li class="block-title"><h3>Notifications</h3></li>',
   );
   // Theme notification items in list for pre-render
   $block['content']['list'] =  array(
     '#theme' => 'item_list__user_notifications',
     '#items' => $items,
     '#pre_render' => array(
       'user_notifications_item_list_child_render'
      ),
    );
  }
}
return $block;
}
```

I have tried to find use cases for my method but so far I am not sure what to pass into $.ajax({}); as options.  I am assuming a 'POST' but what.  I tried using just url:'user_notifications/notify' but I got a 500 error.  currently I am getting an "unexpected identifier" error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.